# Wordpress: creating right/left post layout

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WP theme and was looking to arrange my archive so that the layout flipped with each post. Essentially, have the featured image thumbnail appear on the left of one post, and then on the right of the next.

Very similar to this: http://equinox-template.blogspot.co.uk/

Has anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a count of the post inside the loop, use it in the even odd fashion. If you are using `WP_Query` instance then it will be `$var->current_post`.

```
<?php
    while (have_posts()): the_post()
    if ($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0):
?>
        Markup for even content
<?php else: ?>
        Markup for odd content
<?php
    endif;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Mark it as the Correct answer then :)